# Should a pointer or a non-const reference be passed in this particular case?

Tags: c++

Suppose the class:

```
struct SimplifiedContainer {
    void add(Node *n); // the key is computed based on `n`
    std::map<int, Node*> myMap;
};
```

The question focuses on the `add` function member, which adds a node to the container. The function takes a non-smart pointer, since the nodes are owned by another container. The question is: should `add` take a `Node&` instead?

Comment: I think this depends on how your Node looks (i.e. how it is returned from the other container) in your client code.  I suspect you want to have Node * n as you already have.

Comment: Is passing `nullptr` valid ?

Comment: "Suppose the class" ... that's a `struct` :).

Comment: @Jarod42 No. The argument will be a valid node.

Comment: I don't know the context, but wouldn't it be interesting to use std::shared_ptr throughout?! So your other container would not hold raw pointers Node* but std::shared_ptr<Node>. In this case your "other container" could be deleted, and the nodes registered in SimplifiedContainer would still be intact. If this makes sense for your case, you should pass const std::shared_ptr<Node>& as argument.

Comment: @sperber The other container possesses unique ownership and stores nodes in the form of std::unique_ptr<Node>.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: "Unique ownership". That means what you're asking us how to do here is _wrong_. Either use smart pointers, or don't, but right now you're sort of using them but trying your best to break them.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: But doesn't this defy the idea behind unique_ptr?! I mean if you have to pass the pointer to someone else... doesn't look like a proper use of unique_ptr to me, but looks like a case where you would use shared_ptr or weak_ptr...

Comment: @sperber If the advice is to use shared_ptr everywhere then you may as well tell him to code in Java.

Comment: @James: No, it depends on what the code is used for. For high performance code you must not use garbage collection. But if this is code for a high level interface and performance is not the main concern, std::shared_ptr is possibly a proper choice.

Comment: @sperber I use unique_ptr, because it gives convenience without any sacrifice of performance, which is indeed top priority in this code.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Did you benchmark the solution with `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, I did not. But why complicate the interface without any reason? I know which container is responsible for destroying the nodes!

Comment: @sperber the logic behind `unique_ptr` is to identify that a single owner is responsible for freeing the object, and the object should not be copied accidentally. It's still OK to have "observers" of such an object, although you have to weigh up convenience vs. safety still.  I'd tend to use shared/weak for situations where we really don't know in the code whether or not the object might be freed out from under us.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: In what way would it be "more complicated"? But I won't be drawn into a debate of smart pointers vs raw pointers here. If you are comfortable with your own personal lifetime guarantees, that's your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one thing you should never do is to get a reference only to take it's address and store it in the container. There are multiple reasons why you should not do it. And since you can not store references directly in the containers as is (yes, you can wrap them in std::ref, which will simply take their pointer, but it does that non-transparantely, and I have seen people not understanding what's happening under the hood) you are left with pointers or pointer-like objects for your interface.

Now, risking terrible downvote, my personal advise is stick with what you have. I see no problem there. You have an entity which manages pointers, and you have an index into the managing container. Rather than making it a shared_ptr (and open code to performance issues associated with with shared_ptr managing, and application developer scratching their heads trying to understand life cycle of the pointer) leave it what it is. Of course, you'd have to make sure index is always in sync with the main container - but if you do not ensure this, you will have much bigger problems than pointer being mismanaged or dangling.

**EDIT**
I am going to list a couple of reasons why doing reference-to-address conversion is ill-advised. First, `operator &` can be overloaded and return something else. While this is a terrible thing to do, people still do that - so your interface might simply break because of that. Second, when function accepts a pointer, anyt decent programmer calling it would verify how the pointer is used (this is why you should provide comments indicating that function stores the pointer, but does't manage it). This way developers would know what to give your function. But functions accepting references are less suspicious, so programmers will gladly give it anything, including local variables. The general understanding is that if you accept a reference, you are find with any reference.

Comment: I like your answer very much. But isn't letting the clients know that the container manages pointers going against encapsulation?

Comment: Also, it would be great to get a pointer to a discussion of the "multiple reasons" that you mentioned.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, not sure what you mean by 'agains incapsulation'. Incapsulation of what? As for why not take reference and extract it's address - I will update the answer.

Comment: That the container stores pointers is an implementation detail. I was taught that implementation details should be hidden from the clients and that this hiding principle is called encapsulation.

Comment: Implementation detail is what you call an implementation detail. If your container goal is to store pointers (as method add assumes), storing pointers is hardly irrelevant for outside world.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning you cannot hide this detail because the client *needs* to know about the expected lifetime issues. For example the client needs to know if it is safe to write:  `{ T x;  container.add(&x); }`

Answer (score 2):

#### My advice:

> The function takes a non-smart pointer, since the nodes are owned by another container

That is not a reason not to use a smart pointer.
In fact, that's *a really good reason* to use a smart pointer.

If your "another container" is not storing smart pointers, it should be (specifically, `std::shared_ptr`).

> Should a pointer or a non-const reference be passed in this particular case?

Neither.

**Accept, and store, a `std::weak_ptr`.**

---

#### My answer:

You are set on storing `std::unique_ptr`s in the owning container, and eschewing the smart pointer safeties for your non-owning container.

I would therefore recommend you stick with pointers:

- for symmetry,
- because you will be storing pointers (you cannot store references [directly] in a container), and it just sort of "feels" right to therefore accept pointers into the routine that'll perform that storage, and
- because it strongly indicates that you are implementing memory management yourself (in that your guarantee regarding the containers' respective lifetimes comes from your brain/documentation/hopes/dreams rather than from actual C++ scoping rules),
- references are better used as transparent aliases that don't have to live for very long, usually for convenience and rarely as logical *handles*.

However, this is *completely* subjective and down to stylistic opinion.

Comment: I assumed the nodes are owned as raw pointers in the other container, but this is still sound.

Comment: @MarkB: Fair point; I've now lampshaded my having assumed the opposite. :)

Comment: The other container possesses unique ownership and stores nodes in the form of std::unique_ptr<Node>. I don't understand why you would pass a smart pointer in this case.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Erm, hang on a minute. Why are you storing pointers to objects owned by `unique_ptr`s? That is completely the inverse of the purpose of `unique_ptr` (with the clue being the word "unique"!!!!). It sounds like you should be storing `shared_ptr`s in the owning container and `weak_ptr`s here (and if you don't understand why you should use these smart pointer types, look up what they do).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning there is a fad in C++ that eveything should be stored in some sort of smart pointer because it's safer. There's an element of truth to that but smart pointers are not the silver bullets they're mad eout to be, and be used to paper over whiat is actually a poor software design. In your case there's no reason you should use any type of smart pointer, a reference is fine and is self documenting.

Comment: @James: This has nothing to do with a "fad". The OP _is_ using smart pointers. So, use smart pointers. Don't pick and choose and fight the model by half-using smart pointers and half-not using smart pointers. The OP is free to abandon them altogether and go back to the raw pointer dark ages if he or she would like, and then my answer would look very different. Thanks for the uninformed downvote, though.

Comment: @Lightness Regarding storing `shared_ptr`, I don't agree that it's necessarily the right answer. There's not enough context here to properly answer the question, but if *other container* has ownership of the nodes and you know the lifetime of the nodes will exceed their use by `SimplifiedContainer`, then it's perfectly fine to store them in `unique_ptr`s in *other container* and pass raw pointers (I'd make it a `Node&` because the argument shouldn't be `nullptr`) to `SimplifiedContainer`. If you must involve smart pointers, this would probably be a good use case for `exempt_ptr`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It looks like some context is in order. I am implementing A*. There is a fast hash for looking up the nodes. This hash owns the nodes. The container in the question is the priority queue (the Open list). Once a node enters the hash, it lives there until the application exits. On the other hand, the Open list ceases to exist as soon as the search completes.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: If you want to make that guarantee yourself, then use raw pointers. Refer to my previous comments.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: I have added a section to my answer that deals with your "I want to do it wrong" case. :)

Comment: Why downvote this? This is a perfectly valid answer coming from person with quite large experience in C++. This voting system really asks for redesign...

Comment: +1 for a concrete criterion: "references are better used as transparent aliases that don't have to live for very long". This might be the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If the `SimplifiedContainer` is owning the Nodes, you should receive a `std::unique_ptr`. To identify if it's the owner or not, just check who's in charge of deleting the node. The deleter is usually the owner.

If the `SimplifiedContainer` is not the owner, then you can receive a reference in your `add` and insert the pointer in the list. However, your class would not be safe against dangling pointers.

The best Pattern for this kind of container would be to implement a container_view (this is exacly what you are trying to do!) which is a non owning view of a container. If it's the case, you can contain a list of `reference_wrapper` you can see the pattern in action on this [page](https://scarvenger.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/c-container-view/)

Comment: It being a container is not a good enough reason to mandate ownership.

Comment: well, containers are usually owner of their resources, even if their resources are `std::weak_ptr`

Comment: You just added a layer of indirection to your argument. In your answer, you're arguing that the logical data must be owned by this container because it's a container, and that therefore the container should store `std::unique_ptr` ... which is impossible if, in fact, the logical data is _not_ owned by the container (which I'm saying is perfectly reasonable).

Comment: The other container does possess unique ownership and stores nodes in the form of std::unique_ptr<Node>.